# How to log full URL in Squid3 ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, proxy, squid

I'm installed Squid3 proxy into ubuntu server and everything is OK but when i check the log file, Squid logs url but if the url has a (?) his logging only what before ? mark and skip what after it.

Exp, if i tried to access this url : http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=bmw

squid will log it as : http://www.youtube.com/results?

My ask here how can i configure squid3 to logging the full url ?

Thanks,
Youssef

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this line to your squid.conf:

strip_query_terms off

More information here: [strip_query_terms](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v3/3.1/cfgman/strip_query_terms.html)

Comment: Missing "s": strip_query_terms off